# Rails 3 -- logging output of all requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I have an app that does a lot of API calls (xml and json).  We want to log our response to all requests (we'll filter our html responses).

In general, we get calls in REST and return JSON or XML.  I am logging these today with an around_filter in the application controller to let me:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :global_request_logging
  def global_request_logging
    # log request
    begin 
      yield
    ensure 
      #log response
    end 
  end 

  rescue_from Exception do |exception| 
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.xml {head 400}  
      # etc for JSON and HTML
    end 
  end 
end
```

The problem I'm having is that where I'm logging the response, we haven't hit the rescue_from block yet, so we're logging that we're returning 200.

This leads me to believe there's a better way/place to be logging the request/response in Rails.  Ideally, I'm looking for a way to log the wire -- as raw as inputs and outputs from the client can be.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Rack middleware, for example:

```
module Rack
  class Snoop
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      status, headers, body = @app.call(env)

      case status
      when 200
        # Who needs weekly status reports?
        mail(:to => "myteamleader@mycompany.com", :subject => "See, I told you the application works!", :body => body)
      when 500
        # A bit of extra motivation to fix these errors
        mail(:to => "ceo@mycompany.com", :subject => "Look boss, the application is broken again!", :body => body)
      end

      [status, headers, body]
    end
  end
end
```

You can use it by putting this in your `config/application.rb` or in one of the `config/environments/ENV.rb`.

```
config.middleware.insert_before(ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, Rack::Snoop)
```

You'll notice that I inserted it  before `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions`, that's because it'll allow to catch the 500 errors caused by internal exceptions. If you want it elsewhere, you can peek at the middleware stack with `rake middleware` and put it where you want with `insert_before` or `insert_after`.

Comment: How do I filter this for a specific URL Pattern, like i want to log all the request/response made from url "/api/v2"...